# Python if statement saying 2 strings are not the same

Tags: python

```
import time
#settings file (file with username/password)
settings = "settings.txt"
#set true to skip login
login = False
while not login:

    print("""
                        /------------------------------\\\n
                        /                              \\\n
                        /  Please Enter Your Username  \\\n
                        /                              \\\n
                        /                              \\\n
                        /------------------------------\\\n
    """)
    username = input()
    print("""\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
                        /------------------------------\\\n
                        /                              \\\n
                        /  Please Enter Your Password  \\\n
                        /                              \\\n
                        /                              \\\n
                        /------------------------------\\\n
    """)
    password = input()
    #open file in read and write mode
    file = open(settings, "r+")
    for line in file:
        if "username: " in line:
            line = line.replace("username: ", "")
            if username == line:
                print("test")
file.close()
```

when i run this and fill it all in it will not print test   i am typeing in username but it will not work.
it gets to `if username == line:
print("test")`
and does not print test

The Script/application is for homework at my school

this is the settings file

```
username: username
password: password
```

Comment: The lines from the file contain a `\n` char at the end.

Comment: Any chance line ends in a newline character? Try `if username == line.strip()`.

Comment: Thanks @Junuxx `line.strip()` works

Comment: One of the reasons triple-quoted strings exist is to enable multi-line string literals without having to explicitly encode newline characters. You can remove the `\n` from the end of each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to check username as string if it is in `txt` file! then you have `\n` at the end of your line or using `line.strip()` for removing the '\n'! so change the if statement to :

```
if username+'\n' == line:  #if user name is txt use 'username'
```

or

```
if username == line.strip():
```

Answer (score 2):

*input* is not the correct function to use here, as it evaluates the value the user entered.
Actually, it is generally unsafe to use it at all.

1. Replace *input* with *raw_input*.
2. Make sure to *strip* each string to remove unseen characters (like space and \n).

Comment: thanks i will have to use that from now on then. if you cant tell i am new to python.

Comment: `input` is the correct function in python 3. `raw_input` was even dropped. But yes, it is incorrect in python 2.